# Snorkeling spot in Nago (Okinawa) accessible without a boat

Tags: diving, okinawa

I am going to [Nago](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Nago) ([Okinawa](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Okinawa), [Japan](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Japan)) , and I have heard about a good  snorkeling spot a few hundred meters from a beach in the area, but I don't have the specific location.

Where around Nago is [snorkeling](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Snorkeling) possible/popular? Preferably with fish and scenery.
Preferably close to the coast as I don't have a boat. It can be a few hundred meters from the coast.

Japanese language is OK.

Comment: *The tag says "diving" but I am only interested in snorkeling. The two share the same tag*

Answer (score 1):

No personal experience, but a there is apparently a popular place for both snorkelling and easy dives, along the coast close to Nago (just south of Motobu Port) called "Gorilla Chop". It's pretty much a straight transliteration for the Japanese version, ゴリラチョップ, so locals should recognise the name if you need directions.

There is parking right beside, although [this](http://www.okinawainfo.net/b-gori.htm) (Japanese) page says there's only room for about ten cars and it can get crowded at times.